# Google app engin, python: Google, Facebook, Twitter, OpenID account

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Do anyone know if there are alternatives of Django-SocialAuth which support Google, Facebook, Twitter and OpenID account.

I prefer webapp version instead of Django.

Or if you have done once would you mind sharing it?

Thanks in million.

Answer (score 1):

try checking out http://code.google.com/p/gaema/

from the gaema introduction,

> gaema is a library that provides
>   various authentication systems for
>   Google App Engine. It is basically the
>   tornado.auth module extracted to work
>   on App Engine and independently of any
>   framework.
>
> It supports login using:
>
> - OpenId
> - OAuth
> - Google Accounts
> - Facebook
> - FriendFeed Twitter
>
> You can use one, all or a mix of these
>   auth methods. This is done with
>   minimal overhead: gaema is small and
>   doesn't have any dependencies, thanks
>   to the awesome work done by the
>   Tornado crew.
>
> gaema only authenticates an user, and
>   doesn't provide persistence such as
>   sessions or secure cookies to keep the
>   user logged in. Because each framework
>   do these things in a different way, it
>   is up to the framework to implement
>   these mechanisms.
>
> You can get gaema from
>   http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gaema.

Comment: Does not seem to exist anymore.